# Не применяется text-decoration к классу

Tags: html, css, классы

Повторял код в точности как [в этом видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltMSrSis9ww&t=1448s&ab_channel=%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%A5%D0%BE%E2%84%A2-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5IT%21) (проблема начинается с 19-ой минуты, и продолжается до 20:25). К классу `.nav__link` не применяется `text_decoration: none;`

```css
/* Nav */

.nav {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav__link {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">П</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">F</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">L</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">К</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Л</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Единственное, что я поменял в коде, это не добавлял `<div class="header__logo">`

Я пробовал применять `text_decoration: none;` к элементу `<a>`, а не к отдельному классу, так всё работает... Может не нужно создавать `<div class="header__inner">`?

Comment: В разметке буква `c` в class была русской. Поменял на латинскую - заработало.

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME,спасибо большое! Сам бы никогда не нашёл.